# how to center and scale data using ployfit

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have a set of points in which i want to fit a line through. In most cases i end up getting Inf or -Inf especially when the lines are either vertical or horizontal. I have seen Matlab's description of centering and scaling, but i do not seem to understand how apply this to my data. Below is an example code, but please note however that it isn't exactly the one with the issue. I have used this because the main code will just be too long to follow.

```
x = [0, 1.81, 3.64, 5.45, 7.27]; 
y = [1, -0.82, -2.64, -4.45, -6.27];

fitline = polyfit([y(1), y(2), y(3), y(4)], [x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4)], 1);

%plot the data
k = linspace(0, 10, 5);
fk = (fitline(1)*k) + fitline(2);

figure, plot(k, fk, 'Color', 'r', 'linewidth', 1);
```

Looking forward to any help/suggestions/advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB's function set `polyfit` and `polyval` will handle the centering (calculation of the mean) and scaling (calculation of the standard deviation) for you.  Use the [third output of `polyfit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html#outputarg_mu) to get the parameters:

```
x = [0, 1.81, 3.64, 5.45, 7.27]; 
y = [1, -0.82, -2.64, -4.45, -6.27];
[fitline,~,mu] = polyfit(y(1:4),x(1:4), 1);
```

And pass them to [`polyval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html):

```
k  = linspace(0, 10, 5);
fk = y = polyval(fitline,k,[],mu);
```

Comment: Thanks @TroyHaskin. It works perfectly, but i wonder why it doesn't work when i use the same approach for plots made on images in the image processing toolbox. Any ideas why this could happen?